# What was John Doe's backstory in the eponymous TV series?

Tags: character, john-doe

The show [*John Doe*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0320038/) from 2002/2003 was cancelled before we found out who John was or where he came from. Does anyone know more about that? John was such an interesting character -- had amnesia, could only see black and white, had access to the sum of human knowledge (like the number of dimples on a golf ball).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Doe_%28TV_series%29), derived from an interview with the series creators in Entertainment Weekly:

> Due to the series' cancellation, the final episode ended with an
>   unresolved cliffhanger, revealing that Digger, John's close friend,
>   was in fact the true leader of the Phoenix Organization. In an
>   interview with Entertainment Weekly, series creators Brandon Camp and
>   Mike Thompson revealed what would have happened and John Doe's true
>   identity.
>
> *"Make that someone who looked like John's friend. The villain unmasked
>   in the finale was actually just a Phoenix member with some fancy
>   facial reconstruction. Turns out, the Phoenix believed Doe was the
>   Messiah and its members were actually protecting Doe from a second
>   group, which wanted him dead. **The truth: Doe was injured in a boating
>   accident. That mark on his chest? A scar left by a piece of shrapnel
>   from the explosion. His Überbrain? A by-product of transcending his
>   body during a near-death experience, traveling to a spiritual plane
>   where all the universe's questions are answered.**"*

Comment: Thank you!! And let me just say, that's a pretty EPIC backstory for the character! I sure wish they'd continued with the series, because that premise has so much potential for great storylines!!!

Comment: Sorry but I realized this is a completely different show! I'm asking about _John from Cincinnati_, which also stars a character named John Doe. Someone had changed my original question!!!

Comment: That's kind of hilarious. 

Answer (score 2):

In [an interview](http://web.archive.org/web/20061202122911/http://www.scifi.com/scifiwire/index.php?category=2&id=34221) (2006) **Dominic Purcell**, the actor who played the titular character, had this to say:

> Apparently **I was the messiah returned**.
>
> **[The Phoenix Organization] were working for the Vatican**. ... The Catholics. **They didn't want it to be revealed that the true Christ had returned.**

From [another interview](http://community.livejournal.com/_prisonbreak/765347.html) (2007) with the actor:

> Well, **John Doe was Christ returned. That’s why he knew everything**,...

Comment: I do wonder why he was color blind (although, there were things he could see in color).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I gave you an up-vote, but I can only mark one of the answers as The Answer (with that green checkmark) so that's all I can do.