# Why was John Doe cancelled?

Tags: cancellation, john-doe

There was a TV series, called [John Doe](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0320038/) I think, about a man who finds himself on a beach with amnesia about his recent past. Yet he find he has an encyclopedic memory and can cleverly apply it. So he has some adventures like a modern Sherlock Holmes trying to help people.

The series was on for a few months I think then it was no more. I just wondered what happened to it? Did it not have much of an audience?

Comment: I'd never heard of it, but IMDb seems to have a 7.9/10 rating for [the series](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0320038/)..

Comment: It got rebooted. It's called blindspot now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was cancelled because of dwindling ratings and being replaced by another show. The same fate that many great shows (*cough*Firefly*cough*) shared.

From [Futoncritic.com](http://www.thefutoncritic.com/news/2003/05/08/fox-lets-the-axe-fall-on-john-doe-15941/5931/): (emphasis mine)

> "John Doe's" search for the truth is over. A source close to the FOX series has informed us the network will not renew the series for a second season. The producers of the drama were informed yesterday about the news.
>
> **The news comes as no surprise after recent reports had the network's support shifting from "Doe" to "Fastlane."** FOX executives had repeatedly stated they hoped to keep one of the two dramas for next season as part of a new Thursday or Friday lineup.
>
> **After debuting to an impressive 9.8 million viewers in September of last year, "Doe's" audience dropped more than 40% by its finale last month (5.8 million viewers).** Among adults 18-49 the erosion was even more noticeable (4.3 vs. 2.4 average rating for the hour) as the series routinely finished third in its time slot among the four major networks.

Comment: Did they ever mention in the show what had been done to 'upgrade' his mental powers?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen the show (yet), but during my research I saw comments that the producers explained everything left open by the cliffhanger after the cancellation. You should open a new question here on the site, I am sure someone can answer this.

Comment: @201044 *"You should open a new question here"* - It seems [there is already one](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/21792/49) which might help you there.

Comment: When I saw some of the episodes I never got the impression there were any religious implications. I just thought some strange organization had done something to enhance his mind.

Comment: The John Doe character was very interesting and that show like the TV shows today 'Limitless' or Elementary' can be inspiring and clever ; I just wish not all of their deductive abilities ( actually it's really inductive reasoning , I think) weren't spewed out at some level of 'hyper-communication'.  So to let 'average' people follow some of the logic the character has to talk in slow motion. It would be more 'instructive' ( yes TV dramas can be instructive) if some set of inductive inferences were displayed in a non-hyper fashion.. That would make such dramas almost educational..